# MySqlConnection really not close

Tags: asp.net, mysql

i've a huge problem. 
Take a look to this sample code

```
private sub FUNCTION1()
      dim conn as new mysqlconnection(myconnstring)
      conn.open
      ---- do something
      FUNCTION2()
      ---- 
      conn.close
end sub

private sub FUNCTION2()
     dim conn as new mysqlconnection(myconnstring)
     .... 
     conn.open
     -- do something
     conn.close
end sub
```

Despite i close regulary all my connection, they remains "open" on the mysql server. 
I know this because i'm using MySQL Administration tool to check how many connection i open "line by line" of my source code.
In fact i get a lot of time "user has exceeded the 'max_user_connections' resource (current value: 5)"
My hoster permit ONLY 5 connection, but i think that if i write GOOD source code, this cannot be a problem. 
So my question is: why that "damn" connections remain open ??
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider wrapping your MySqlConnection operations in a `Using` statement...

Any object that you instantiate within that `Using ... new` statement will be disposed of properly by the compiler. Once that `End Using` statement appears, the object goes out of scop. Any objects that are declared with in the `Using` block will need to be disposed of by the developer, as per normal.

```
Using conn As New MySqlConnection(myConnString)
  Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Employees", conn)
    conn.Open()
      Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While rdr.Read()
          Console.WriteLine(rdr(0))
        End While
      End Using
  End Using
End Using
```

In this case, you don't HAVE to encase your Command and Reader in their own `Using`, but it allows you to take advantage of the fact that they all implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: hi campbell, what happen if i use the "using" statemnet only for the connection ? does the reader and command will be disposed after the end of using statement ?

Comment: This solution solved my connection issues with the asp.net mysql connector.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling conn.Dispose() and then setting it to null.
On another note, are you opening a connection in Function1 and Function2 also as it appears that you're creating 2 connections. If that's the case try to implement a singleton pattern to manage your connections.